# Real-time waveform rendering with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a Waveform library that renders real-time audio from microphone, however is there any pure javascript library that does this job.

There are lots of library that does render waveforms out of audio files wav, mp3, ogg etc (one of which I use in my project) but I haven't seen anything that renders waveform real-time audio from microphone.

Comment: So what are you asking for, where did you get stuck? Fetching input from the microphone? Finding a renderer lib that is capable of doing it real-time?

Comment: check this, may help - http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#dom-navigator-getusermedia

Comment: @Bergi I can get the data from mic and then pass it on the waveform rendered, problem is that is is too slow

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far. Did you already found the bottleneck?